# Update Index of the child views of Linear Layout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Hi I am developing an application in which I am adding the image in Scrollview and maintaning the arraylist of image urls on same click. If there are 10 images in scrollview then there will be 10 urls in the Arraylist. Now I have delete button on each item of scrollview and want to delete the image and repective image url from the arraylist but Iam getting arrayIndexoutofbound exception after deletion of 2-3 images. Here is my Code:

```
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(image_url.size()<15)
                {
                list.get(position).put("count",String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).get("count"))+1));

                 image_url.add(imageUrls.get(position));
                 DynamicView(list_views, imageUrls.get(position));
                 count.setText("("+image_url.size()+")");

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max 15 images can be selected.", 89).show();
                }

              notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

  int j;
private void DynamicView(final LinearLayout dynamic, String url){

      LayoutInflater linflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      for( j=0;j<image_url.size();j++);

      {
          final View customView2 = linflater2.inflate(R.layout.view_item,null);

         RelativeLayout image=(RelativeLayout)customView2.findViewById(R.id.rel_image);
         ImageView cross=(ImageView)customView2.findViewById(R.id.cross);

         Bitmap l = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(url, 200, 200);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(l);
         image.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        cross.setId(j);
        customView2.setId(j);
         cross.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // int size=image_url.size();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        System.out.println("id =="+arg0.getId());
            dynamic.removeView(customView2);
            image_url.remove(arg0.getId());
            count.setText("("+image_url.size()+")");
            System.out.println("size 1= =="+image_url.size());
            System.out.println("size  2 =="+dynamic.getChildCount());
            dynamic.getChildAt(arg0.getId());

            }
        });
         dynamic.addView(customView2);
}
```

Here is some thing going wrong , please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you removing the specific index of your arraylist as well when you delete some row if not then truncate your arraylist as well

Comment: yes I am removing but as given in the code above I am confused what to do on this stage.